# differentiate between maven multi module and Spring micro services?

Tags: microservices

I am reading spring micro services for next project. Tut said that "The architecture style the main application divided in a set of sub applications called microservices. One large Application divided into multiple collaborating processes.". So already we have a framework maven multi module There I separated the project in my experience. even though it is. why do we need micro services to separate a project?. please differentiate it. thanks in advance..

Comment: If you read up on the benefits of microservices it should be clear what the difference is with a multi-module maven project. I'm voting to close this.

Comment: @nicoVanBelle yes I read it but i could not understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every service in the microservice architecture should be isolated which means that the team in charge of that service is able to put continuous deployment in practice without need to deploy other services. In practice, IMHO I think that we can use two approaches using our favourite build tool such as `maven` or `gradle`:

- Monoproject: domain, repositories, services and controllers are all in the same project.
- Multiproject: domain, repositories, services and controllers can be grouped in different modules. i.e domain and repositories are in repository module and services in another module with the same name and controllers in front module.

But, doesn't matter which approach you use the project (mono or multi) should represent one service.